# How to show an image overlay only for specific applications?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-service

I want to create a image overlay, behaving like the "chat head service" of the Facebook app, but which will show or hide depending on the application currently in the foreground. For example, if the app currently in the foreground is Gmail or Hangouts, the image overlay should be visible, else it should be gone.

I had no problem with creating and running the service which shows the overlay, with the drag-and-drop feature and all. I'm stuck with how the service can show or hide the overlay, in other terms how it can precisely detect foreground change.

I have read many posts suggesting ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(), but this feature is deprecated since Lollipop, and does not work correctly since. 
Some other suggestions are about using Accessibility Service, but I do not want to use it, mainly because my app has nothing to do with accessibility.

The exact behavior that I want to reproduce is the one implemented in the "Popemoji" app. It may not be a brilliant design, but it works consistently on Android 4+, and it does not require Accessibility permissions.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: In general, Android has been working steadily to prevent apps from finding out what other app is in the foreground, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, and yes, I agree with you. I'm kind of obstinate with that subject because there is the "Popemoji" implementation exemple, which makes exactly what I'm trying to do.